# Spark - Task Scheduler Error while parsing JSON

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, rdd, json4s

I'm trying to read 5 terabytes of json into an RDD of custom objects using `json4s`. There are 50,000 files of around 100 MB each. For some reason, if I set my executor size to 16G, I get the following error.

```
ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor foo on bar: Remote RPC client 
disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network 
issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
```

My code is as follows:

```
val input = sc.textFile(inPath)
val operations = input.mapPartitions(row => {
      row.flatMap(record => {
        try {
          implicit val formats = DefaultFormats  // formats not serializable
          Some(parse(record).extract[MyClass])
        } catch {
          case e: Exception => None
        }
      })
    })
```

I do not get this problem when reading in hundreds of Gigs of data. If I increase the executor memory to 55G, it works but this seems inefficient. Each zipped file is only 100 MB after all, probably not more than 1 Gig unzipped. I would have thought I'd be able to spin up a ton of 8 Gig or even 4 Gig executors to read the data in.

Comment: Spark is in-memory computation. So you will need lot of memory if you have lot of data.

Comment: Couldn't this be achieved through more executors? Why would you need more memory on a single executor?

Comment: what is the cause of that error ? Is it being caused by `Direct buffer memory` overflow or some other memory section overflow ? The error message that you provided can come up in case of more than one problems. Provide the full error details.

Comment: Oddly there is no other error. I just get mesos task lost and then this message.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was due to memoryOverhead being too low. At 16 gigs, I set it to 6000.

```
--conf spark.mesos.executor.memoryOverhead=6000
```